# One Class Classification for recommending perfect bouquet of flowers

Tags: machine-learning, classification, one-class

For my university project I have the following problem and I am wondering what might be the best approach to solve it:

Say, I want to generate the best bouquet of flowers as a florist based on flowers the customer has in their hands.

They are giving me tulips and gerberas and I will recommend them the best bouquet, based on bouquets I have learned with tulips and gerberas in it.

I have learned only bouquets that are real and possible to recreate so my training data would look something like this:

```
    Rose  Tulip Gerbera ... Sunflower Lily  |  y 
b1  1     1      0      ...    1      0     |  1
b2  0     1      1      ...    1      1     |  1 
...                     ...                  ...                                            
bn  0     0      0      ...    1      1     |  1
```

So as I only have learned good looking bouquets, my idea was to use soft classification to determine which flowers could fit to the handed tulips and gerberas. As n is very high (around 100.000) a mutli classification would not be possible in this case.

My question is, would this be the right approach to recommend great bouquets or would it make sense to randomly generate some ugly bouquets and set the target value to 0 to let the machine learn how a bouquet should not look like. It is very important that the flowers the customer is giving should be a good looking bouquet as I cannot change the customers wish to combine certain flowers. I just need the closest good looking bouquet to choose this and make it look great. 
Or might there be a simpler approach than classification?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to comment, so first I'll ask: what is y? Unless you can create examples of ugly bouquets, I do not think a supervised learning approach is best. Even if you created ugly bouquets, there would be a very wide space of ugliness to cover.

If your goal is to recommend a bouquet, I would approach this problem by seeing what bouquets were made with the flowers a customer has. I'll assume that the examples of bouquets are beautiful bouquets. You can see which previously made bouquets you can make with a customer's flowers, allowing to recreate one of those bouquets.

Another approach would be clustering to see which historical bouquet clusters your customer's flowers are most similar to. If you look at the average makeup of bouquets per cluster, you can determine which one your customer can fall into.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @thomaskolasa. 
y is my dependent variable so this would be my only class 1. Yes, my goal is to recommend beautiful bouquets. So for this problem maybe a vector space model with e.g. the calculation of the cosine similarity would be enough? I just tried to find the most efficient way :)  
I am not sure if clustering would work since some flowers are present in almost every bouquet and therefore at least the sklearn clustering algorithms create a quite big cluster and some smaller clusters but I will still try it out.

Comment: The most important take away is that since there's only 1 class, this is not a supervised learning problem. With regards to clustering: if 1 flower is in say 95%+ of the bouquets, perhaps you could try sklearn's `VarianceThreshold` to cut low variance flowers and cluster without that flower.